# Getting 3 or 4 players working in Rayman Origins with non-360 (XINput) controllers

Tags: controllers, rayman-origins, xpadder, x360ce

After a large amount of work, I still can't get more than 2 players working in Rayman Origins.

I have 2 official xbox 360 controllers which work, but I cannot get any of my other controllers working for player 3 or player 4. My other controllers support directInput and are recognised by windows and in other games.

I tried using x360ce to emulate more 360 controllers, but the game doesn't recognise them.

I tried using xPadder to emulate keyboard commands, but the game doesn't recognise those, either (maybe it doesn't let you use keyboard for some playes and 360 for others? That'd be a pretty dopey omission...)

I tried looking for config files for the game I can edit, no luck yet.

The PCGamingWiki page didn't help.

Has anyone succeeded in have 3 or more players in this game? How?

Comment: With 4 Xbox controllers. That worked easy enough for me...

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get three players working by plugging in **only** my x360 Wireless Gaming Reciever and one USB controller (actually a USB adapter for a SNES pad). Then the game finally recognised the two 360 controllers as players 1 and 2, and responded to input from the third control pad (SNES pad through USB adapter) as player 3. I was able to configure the buttons in the in-game settings menu and play.

This worked without x360ce or xPadder.

Perhaps my original problem was caused by having adapters for more than four controllers plugged in at once? I'm using USB adapters that are acknowledged by windows as controllers (in the directx Game Controllers control panel) even when the actual Gamecube/SNES controller isn't actually plugged into the USB adapter.

So try unplugging some stuff if you have this issue.